# Is there a function in Haskell that returns the type of its argument (or a string showing the type)?

Tags: haskell

Is there a function one can call within a Haskell program that does what `:t` does interactively? Or is this something Haskell cannot do since it's type would not make sense.  What about a function that returned the name of the type as a String?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`typeOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf) is the canonical way to do this. Beware that it doesn't (can't) handle polymorphism as well as tools outside the language can.

```
Data.Typeable> typeOf ()
()
Data.Typeable> typeOf "hi"
[Char]
Data.Typeable> typeOf 3 -- hmmm....
Integer
Data.Typeable> typeOf id -- HMMMMMM...
<interactive>:4:1: error:
    • No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of ‘typeOf’
    • In the expression: typeOf id
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = typeOf id
```

Answer (score 10):

This is not something that Haskell programmers commonly want or need. So if you want this feature, you are doing something unusual. This can be because you are a beginner and still getting used to program in Haskell (in that case – what are you trying to achieve?). Or you are beyond beginner and want to experiment with unusual feature (in that case – read on).

- If you are looking for a function that takes a `String`, interprets it as a Haskell term type-checks it and gives you its string, then you can embedd the Haskell compiler in your program. Look at the [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) library.
- If you are in a polymorphic context and want, maybe for debugging, know the type that some type variable `a` is bound to, then the [`Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) type class can provide you this information: `show (typeOf x)` gives you the concrete type of the value referenced by the term `x`. You may have to add `Typeable a` constraints to your polymorphic function.

Comment: Mainly curious how it could be done. I see that `typeOf` requires its argument's type to be an instance of `Typeable`. Is the implication that all types are automatically `Typeable`? I just defined my own type. GHCi happily applied `typeOf` to one of its instances and returned the newly defined type even though I didn't declare my type an `instance` of `Typeable`.

Comment: In the previous comment I said that I defined my own type. It was `data X = Xi`. Then: > typeOf Xi  -> X; > typeOf (typeOf Xi) --> SomeTypeRep; > typeOf (typeOf (typeOf Xi)) --> SomeTypeRep

Comment: Yes, GHC creates `Typeable` instances automatically: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-typeable-instances

Answer (score 2):

The question can be understood twofold:

1. can a polymorphic function inquire the concrete type it is called with. The other questions describe how it could be done.
2. can we get to runtime statically known information about a binding. This is what actually the `:t` does. There are ways to get it:

a. to just print it during compilation, you could enable PartialSignatures extension, and add to arbitrary expression signature `:: _`, then its type will be printed during compilation.

b. to actually get the type as a data for runtime handling, you could use TemplateHaskell extension and function `reify` from it.

Answer (score 1):

This works well with monomorphic arrow types:

```
λ> typeOf (id @Int)
Int -> Int
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who like me stumble into here looking for a way to name a type variable in a pattern-matched existential type (for instance to use it in a visible type application), it's a little obvious in hindsight, but you need ScopedTypeVariables and to specify an in-line type signature, e.g.

```
data Existential where
  Existential :: Typeable a => a -> Existential

typeInExistential :: Existential -> TypeRep
typeInExistential (Existential (x :: a)) = typeRep (Proxy @a)
```

(this is a slightly convoluted example, but you get the idea)